# Pulling NPM Private Module from Non-Master Branch

Tags: node.js, github, branch, npm

Currently pulling in our data layer at work with a line in our package.json that looks like this:

"repoName": "git+ssh://git@github.com:companyName/repoName.git"

Would like to know how I can pull in a different branch of the repo through NPM so that I can experiment without affecting the branch that the production servers pull from?

Any alternative ideas are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull it with a branch by adding a hash `#` after the link.

```
"repoName": "git+ssh://git@github.com:companyName/repoName.git#branch"
```

This can also work for a tag `#0.1.2` or a specific commit hash id `#b50b5e4787c988fed89b018d10064279311fffe7`.